# How to Map Id in List?

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

```
Dictionary<int, string> lstSrc = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            Dictionary<int, string> lstDest = new Dictionary<int, string>();

        lstSrc.Add(1, "All");
        lstSrc.Add(2, "Weekday");
        lstSrc.Add(3, "WeekEnd");

        lstDest.Add(1, "All");
        lstDest.Add(2, "X1");
        lstDest.Add(3, "X2");
        lstDest.Add(4, "Weekday");
        lstDest.Add(5, "WeekEnd");
```

Compare only when name matches in Source and Destination

```
  var matchingItems = lstDest
                    .Where(l2 => lstSrc.Any(l1 => l1.Value.Equals(l2.Value))).ToList();
                matchingItems.AddRange(lstDest.Except(matchingItems));
```

This query gives result as see in attached image how to get that result without using LINQ ?

How i can achieve this ?

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLicZ.png
```

Comment: So you want everything that's in the first list or in the second list?

Comment: I am having a fairly difficult time understanding your question.  Could you be more clear?  Do the 2 code boxes at the top represent example lists? or do they represent a single element in the list?

Comment: Ah ok, I was guessing wrong..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the matching items you could use a query like this:

```
var matchingItems = List2
    .Where(l2 => List1.Any(l1 => l1.TimeGroupName.Equals(l2.TimeGroupName));
matchingItems.AddRange(List2.Except(matchingItems)));
```

Edited: equivalent without using Linq: (It's easy to forget how much boiler plate Linq saves you from writing!)

```
// Get the matching items
List<TIMEGROUPINFO> matchingItems = new List<TIMEGROUPINFO>();
foreach (TIMEGROUPINFO l1 in List1)
{
    foreach (TIMEGROUPINFO l2 in List2)
    {
       if (l1.TimeGroupName.Equals(l2.TimeGroupName))
       {
            matchingItems.Add(l1);
            continue;
       }
    }
 }

 // Append the items from List2 which aren't already in the list:
 foreach (TIMEGROUPINFO l2 in List2)
 {
     bool exists = false;
     foreach (TIMEGROUPINFO match in matchingItems)
     {
         if (match.TimeGroupName.Equals(l2.TimeGroupName))
         {
             // This item is already in the list.
             exists = true;
             break;
         }
     }

     if (exists = false)
         matchingItems.Add(l2);
 }
```

Comment: It's just not possible in one go - I think my addition should provide the desired result.

Comment: @Staurt : Your Linq query gives me expected result , but i am using Dot Net 2.0 so linq concept there.How i can achieve the same without using LINQ ?

Comment: @Stuart : Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute (Getting this exception)

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to perform a query on list 2 based on list 1.  Linq is very good for that.

so, if you wrote something like

```
//List1Element is a single element in the first list.  
List1Element = List1[i];

List2.Where(l2 => l2.TimeGroupName == List1Element.TimeGroupName).ToList();
```

That might accomplish what I think you're trying to accomplish.

If you're trying to match the entire List1 at once, you can either iterate through all the list1 elements, or you can look into [Linq Join](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-Join-Operators-dabef4e9) operations